# Sleek way of un/commenting out html tags in markdown

Tags: python, html, regex, lambda

I'm trying to find a nice way of wrapping html tags in html comments without writing 5 functions and 50 lines of code. Using an example code :

```
<section class="left span9">
### Test
</section>
```

I need to transform it to :

```
<!--<section class="left span9">-->
### Test
<!--</section>-->
```

I have a regex to find the tags

```
re.findall('<.*?>', str)
```

but in the last years I wasn't using lambdas too often so now I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

btw any ideas for the reverse of this process - decommenting the tags ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can comment/uncomment using simple `replace` like this

```
myString = '<section class="left span9">'
print myString.replace("<", "<!--<").replace(">", ">-->")
print myString.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", "")
```

**Output:**

```
<!--<section class="left span9">-->
<section class="left span9">
```

**Note:** This works because, a valid HTML document should have `<` and `>` only in the HTML tags. If they should appear, as they are, in the output, they have to be properly HTML escaped with `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: I think the question is to *add* the uncommenting tags. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so temporarily I've ended up using two functions and re.sub for that :

```
def comment(match):
    return '<!--'+match.group(0)+'-->'

def uncomment(html):
    return html.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')

commented_html = re.sub('<.*?>', comment, html_string)

uncommented_html = uncomment(commented_html)
```